# implement angular2-virtual-scroll with observable in angular4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, observable, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to implement angular2-virtual-scroll in an angular4 project. Firstly, can anyone confirm if I would have a problem implementing it in NG4. I don't think I should and I haven't seen any notices to the contrary. Secondly I am using an observable instead of a promise shown in the NPM angular2-virtual-scroll docs. However, when I applied the virtual-scroll tag there is no change in my output...no scroll bar ..the data from the observable is displayed but no scrolling. The following are the relevant code segments:

**Home.component.html**

```
<h1 style="color: #76323f">
  {{title}}
</h1>

<h4>
  {{description}}
</h4>
<h2>Coming Soon....</h2>
<app-events-list [upcomingEvents]="upcomingEvents"></app-events-list>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {UpcomingEvent}       from './../../interface/upcomingevent';
import {EventService}        from './../../services/event.service';
import {Subscription}        from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  upcomingEvents: Array<UpcomingEvent>;
  title = 'Welcome....';
  description='Events promotions....';
  eventServiceSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService){
    this.upcomingEvents = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventServiceSub=this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(upcomingEvents=>{this.upcomingEvents=upcomingEvents.slice(0,25);
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    if (this.eventServiceSub){
      this.eventServiceSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  } 
}
```

**event-list-component.html**

```
    <virtual-scroll [items]="items" (update)="upcomingEvents = $event"
    (change)="onlistChange($event)">
     <app-upcomingevent *ngFor="let upcomingEvent of upcomingEvents"[upcomingEvent]="upcomingEvent" [eventItemCss]="'event-item'"></app-upcomingevent>
     <div *ngIf="loading" class="loader">Loading.....</div>
    </virtual-scroll>
```

**event-list-component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UpcomingEvent } from './../../interface/upcomingevent';
import { trigger,state,style,transition,animate,keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
import { ChangeEvent } from 'angular2-virtual-scroll';
import {EventService}        from './../../services/event.service';
import {Subscription}        from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events-list',
  templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css'],
  animations: []
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


 @Input()
 upcomingEvents: Array<UpcomingEvent>;

 items=this.upcomingEvents;
 protected buffer: Array<UpcomingEvent> =[];
 protected loading: boolean;
 eventServiceSub: Subscription;


 constructor(private eventService: EventService) { 
    this.upcomingEvents=[];
 }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if (this.eventServiceSub){
      this.eventServiceSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  } 

  protected onlistChange(event: ChangeEvent){
    if (event.end !==this.buffer.length) return;
    this.loading=true;

    this.eventServiceSub=this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(upcomingEvents=>{
         this.buffer=upcomingEvents.slice(this.buffer.length,25);
         this.loading=false;
      }, ()=> this.loading=false);
   }
 }
```

**eventService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {UpcomingEvent} from './../interface/upcomingevent'
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getEvents(): Observable<UpcomingEvent[]>
  {
    return this.http
       .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
       .map(response => response.json() as UpcomingEvent[]);

  }
}
```

**upcomingEvents.html**

```
<md-card [ngClass]="'event-item'">
  <h4 [ngClass]="'event-title'" [ngStyle]="{'color':'purple'}"> {{upcomingEvent.title}}</h4>    
   <md-card-actions>
    <button md-button>LIKE</button>
    <button md-button>SHARE</button>
   </md-card-actions>
</md-card>
```

**upcomingEvents.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UpcomingEvent } from './../../interface/upcomingevent';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-upcomingevent',
  templateUrl: './upcomingevent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upcomingevent.component.css']
})
export class UpcomingeventComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input()
 upcomingEvent: UpcomingEvent;

 @Input()
 eventItemCss: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.upcomingEvent) {
     this.upcomingEvent=<UpcomingEvent> {}; 
     }

    }

}
```

The way it suppose to work is that the HomeComponent request data from the eventService via an observable..the data is then passed to the eventList component where it is iterated on and pass to the upcomingEvents component to present via HTML. 25 events are requested at first and if the user scroll to the end another 25 is requested from the eventService...this time by the upcomingEvents component. I am not sure this is the most efficient way to do it but in either case it doesn't work. The virtual-scroll seems to have no effect on the output....I would really appreciate someone showing me what I am doing wrong....Thanks

Comment: have you thought about using a library (eg [this](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll))?

Comment: I did take a look at nix-infinite-scroll but the documentation didn't impress me. Appeared to be written for the advanced user. I am a newbie at angular so I need good documentation.

Comment: Also I would think that ng2-virtual-scroll qualify in this context

Comment: Ok. As I understood virtual scroll does't fire `update` event. Please, include code of this component.

Comment: @SergeySokolov if you are speaking of update the display to the next item in the buffer then I believe this line  <virtual-scroll [items]="items" (update)="upcomingEvents = $event"
    (change)="onlistChange($event)"> in event-list-component.html should do it.

Comment: @SergeySokolov  if you are speaking of retrieving more data from the api then that's what the observable should do in this snip of event-list-component.ts.......this.eventServiceSub=this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(upcomingEvents=>{
         this.buffer=upcomingEvents.slice(this.buffer.length,25);
         this.loading=false;
      }, ()=> this.loading=false);

Comment: MichaelE, Sorry I misunderstood you. When you said that `either case it doesn't work` you meant that you don't see first 25 items? Does you service is actually called? If you remove `virtual scroll` element will the events lisst be rendered?

Comment: @SergeySokolov Yes I do see the 25 items ...the just as I did without the virtual scroll. Yes the service is working......as I mention in the question.....the data from the observable is displayed but no scrolling....no scroll bar nothing

Comment: if you see items but do not see scroll, then most likely you need to set `height` of `app-events-list` element.

Comment: If you want to use Observables, maybe try this Observable-based implementation in A4: https://github.com/dinony/od-virtualscroll

Features a lot of examples!

Comment: @dinony ....I will take a look an report back if it works...thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a problem in your code. When using virtual-scroll you need to keep two arrays - one for all loaded data, and one for currently rendered items. Looks like you kinda mixed them up.

Let's call all-items-array as `items` and render-array - `upcomingEvents`

First chunk of items will be passed from the parent component, hence:

**Home.component.html**

```
...
<app-events-list [items]="upcomingEvents"></app-events-list>
```

**event-list-component.html** looks good

**event-list-component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UpcomingEvent } from './../../interface/upcomingevent';
import { trigger,state,style,transition,animate,keyframes } from '@angular/animations';
import { ChangeEvent } from 'angular2-virtual-scroll';
import {EventService}        from './../../services/event.service';
import {Subscription}        from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events-list',
  templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css'],
  animations: []
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


 @Input()
 items: Array<UpcomingEvent> = [];

 upcomingEvents: Array<UpcomingEvent>;

 protected loading: boolean;
 eventServiceSub: Subscription;


 constructor(private eventService: EventService) { 
    this.upcomingEvents=[];
 }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if (this.eventServiceSub){
      this.eventServiceSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  } 

  protected onlistChange(event: ChangeEvent){
    if (event.end !==this.items.length) return;
    this.loading=true;

    this.eventServiceSub=this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(upcomingEvents=>{
         this.items=upcomingEvents.slice(0, this.items.length + 25);
         this.loading=false;
      }, ()=> this.loading=false);
   }
 }
```

**warning!** code not tested, I simply edited your code.

Comment: I will test and let you know

Comment: The test resulted in no data...no list. It appears that we lost the data received from the api somewhere along the line.....Thanks for your suggestion.